# WebRTC: Does it matter where my TURN server is?

Tags: webrtc, turn

**Context**: I am going to be setting up a **support app** for global customers. All my customers are going to be connecting to our support agents who are in **one location**.

**Question**: Is there any advantage to also having TURN servers closer to the customers, or is it just as well to have all my TURN servers near my support agents?

**Current Understanding**: If I understand it right, the connection between Peer 1 and Peer 2 is linear through the TURN servers, i.e.

Peer 1 -> TURN 1 -> TURN 2 -> Peer 2

It seems that it wouldn't matter which leg of that journey is longer unless there's some non-linear behavior leading to a lengthier round-trip leg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the customer is using TURN/TCP on the Peer 1 -> TURN 1 leg. Doing that on high-latency global links is probably going to result in slightly worse quality than having a udp TURN 1 -> TURN 2 link.

See [this blog post](https://medium.com/the-making-of-appear-in/where-to-deploy-turn-or-other-relay-servers-2dab2e8157ea) for TURN deployment considerations and metrics to track.